# Based on Text field automatically fillup in the progress in Ionic angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to show progress bar when i entered the fields.

Based on fields fillup automatically need to show the proress bar using angularjs in ionic.

[image]

Comment: So you would like a percentage based on how many fields have been filled out? Do you have any validation on the fields? How is your model structured?

Comment: we have validations and when ever i focus and entered the some data and going to another field in that time percentage i need to show in progress bar. we done validation but we unable to give progress bar. if you have any sample please provide

Comment: like this http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/xtLcD it is in jquery. i want in angular js. any one help me how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBBGgj

You need to track the progress based on the validation of the input.

```
  function validateInput(input, arrayLength) {
    console.log(input);
    if (!input.validated && input.model.length > 3) {
      vm.validationProgress = vm.validationProgress + (100 / arrayLength);
      input.validated = true;
      console.log(vm.validationProgress);
    } else if (input.validated && input.model.length <= 0) {
      input.validated = false;
      vm.validationProgress = vm.validationProgress - (100 / arrayLength);
    }
  }
```

This code can be improved upon, and you should probably find a better solution to it, but it should point you in the right direction.

If an input is validated = true, I color the progressbox for that input green.

```
<div ng-repeat="input in vm.inputfields" ng-class="{ 'validated' : input.validated }" class="validation-item">
```

Comment: thanks Stian..Exact i want like that But i want input field code in html page, i don't want to append from js to html page. and also i entered all fields and showing 100% progress but if i clear any field i want to reduce the progress bar from last position not for exact position. Right now which field i cleared in that position only clearing the progress. Can you help in this scenario.